# MultipleThreads and synchronization Thread Visibility

Tags: java, concurrency

Say I have a Thread T1. I create an object in that thread e.g. `Dog` and set some properties (`name`, `color`) etc.

I then thread another Thread T2 (from T1) and pass the `Dog` object to it. After this point, T1 doesn't change anything properties of the object and doesn't even want to read it, but holds onto the actual reference (`Dog d`).

Question:

1. Assuming T2 doesn't change anything in `Dog`, is Dog Thread safe (from visibility stand-point. Will T2 always see the same name and color as set by T1)?

Comment: both threads do not change Dog instance, it is definitely thread safe

Comment: Just because you choose not to mutate an object doesn't mean it's threadsafe. Using that logic, *everything* would be threadsafe. You seem to be talking about visibility in terms of Java's thread caching rather than thread *safety*

Answer (score 2):

Every actions in a thread can see whatever happened before that thread was started. In your example, T2 is guaranteed to see all changes made by T1 before `t2.start()` was called.

That does not make `Dog` thread safe but your use of that class is thread safe.

Note however that any subsequent changes made by either T1 or T2 after that point are not guaranteed to be visible from the other thread.

---

Reference: [JLS #17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-320):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

Answer (score 1):

`Dog` is thread safe only if the values are just instance variables and volatile.

If they are not volatile there is a chance that T2 could read stale data.

Comment: No need for volatile in the OP's example.

Comment: could you elaborate on that? different threads can always cause reads to the cache instead of reads of the correct value if you did not mark the variable as volatile.

Comment: if you have this sequence: [In T1]: `dog.setName("doggy"); T2.start();` and [in T2] `println(dog.getName());` - you have the guarantee to print `doggy` in T2 or possibly a more recent value. That's because `t2.start()` acts as a memory barrier, preventing T2 from reading an older value.

Comment: I can't find this memory barrier thing at the java memory model docs. Where do they say this?

Comment: just saw your other answer!

Answer (score 0):

As long as:

- your implementation guarantees being free of race conditions when accessing properties of your `Dog d` object by multiple threads simultaneously

or

- `Dog d`'s properties' access is protected from race conditions

... you can consider it to be thread safe.

I would say that right now it is not possible to say whether your solution is thread safe or not. Because nothing is mentioned about data accessing principles or locks.

I suspect it is not thread safe!

Answer (score -1):

"is Dog Thread safe?" If its not immutable then I'd say no.

"from visibility stand-point. Will T2 always see the same name and color as set by T1?" Probably. (watch out if things are not volatile or synchronized.

Simple way to handle this is to synchronize on it. that will make it thead-safe.

Comment: mutability does not preclude thread safety. if you have volatile variables they are thread safe since you will not be able to read stale data. it's just simpler to guarantee thread safety if the values are immutable and you do computation on them.

Comment: Which is why I said "probably", however no info was given on the inside details of Dog. I dont like to speculate.

Comment: OP clearly said that Dog (and its properties) is not changed after creation of thread T2. So for this particular case Dog has become immutable (not in real sense) after creation of T2 and hence thread safe.

Comment: If Dog is immutable then the simple answer 'YES, it is thread safe', however without seeing Dog or having the OP clearly state 'Dog is immutable' I don't believe we can speculate that.